# Downloading mulitple images through scrapy in a single page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi this is my code to scrape multiple images in scrapy but its only scraps one image.

Can you tell me where i am wrong?

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = DmozItem()
    image_urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="overhid"]//img/@src').extract()
    item['image_urls'] = [ x for x in image_urls]
    return item
```

Comment: Could you share the url you are web-scraping? Or, at least show the contents of `div` with `class="overhid"`? Thanks.

Comment: this is the link  [link](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/xolo-win-q900s-black/770747222)  and through xpath i am able to see 6 images links.Is my code right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that other images have `lazysrc` attribute instead of `src`. Get both of the attributes:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.snapdeal.com/product/xolo-win-q900s-black/770747222
>>> for image in response.xpath('//div[@class="overhid"]//img'):
...     print image.xpath('@src | @lazysrc').extract()[0]
... 
http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-1-9dbe9.jpg
http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-2-1c8f7.jpg
http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-3-09694.jpg
http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-4-af867.jpg
http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-5-73467.jpg
http://n2.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-6-5c97f.jpg
```

Here's how you should change your `parse()` callback:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = DmozItem()
    images = response.xpath('//div[@class="overhid"]//img')
    item['image_urls'] = [image.xpath('@src | @lazysrc').extract()[0] 
                          for image in images]
    return item
```

Comment: hey for this what changes i have to made in my code

Comment: thanks bro its working awesome also can u tell one thing in my image-url "http://n4.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/k/9/small/Xolo-WIN-Q900s-Black-SDL051074306-1-9dbe9.jpg" there is a "small" word which i want to remove because due to this i am getting small image.can u tell me a way to do so?